# Highcharts Maps - Displaying data on Highmaps

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am attempting to display my data on a Highmaps map with the same exact layout as the 'Small US with data lables' demo

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/maps/us-data-labels

I am keeping everything the same; one thing I am removing is the list of states in HTML that display under the map. Just simply changing the percentages that show when hovering over each state. This is where I run into issues. I am trying to display my `stateData` percentages but when doing so the map returns empty and does not show anything else other than the state abbreviations.

```
const stateData = [{ state: "Alaska", percentage: 0.3 },
 { state: "Arizona", percentage: 1.79 },
 { state: "Arkansas", percentage: 0.82 },
 { state: "California", percentage: 12.34 },
 { state: "Colorado", percentage: 1.94 },
 { state: "Connecticut", percentage: 1.2 },
 { state: "Delaware", percentage: 0.3 },
 { state: "District of Columbia", percentage: 0.37 },
 { state: "Florida", percentage: 5.78 },
 { state: "Georgia", percentage: 2.92 },
 { state: "Hawaii", percentage: 0.53 },
 { state: "Idaho", percentage: 0.53 },
 { state: "Illinois", percentage: 3.98 },
 { state: "Indiana", percentage: 1.88 },
 { state: "Iowa", percentage: 1 },
 { state: "Kansas", percentage: 0.86 },
 { state: "Kentucky", percentage: 1.13 },
{ state: "Louisiana", percentage: 1.36 },
 { state: "Maine", percentage: 0.58 },
 { state: "Maryland", percentage: 1.67 },
 { state: "Massachusetts", percentage: 2.44 },
{ state: "Michigan", percentage: 2.84 },
 { state: "Minnesota", percentage: 1.65 },
 { state: "Mississippi", percentage: 0.77 },
 { state: "Missouri", percentage: 1.77 },
{ state: "Montana", percentage: 0.49 },
 { state: "Nebraska", percentage: 0.63 },
 { state: "Nevada", percentage: 0.93 },
 { state: "New Hampshire", percentage: 0.52 },
 { state: "New Jersey", percentage: 2.96 },
{ state: "New Mexico", percentage: 0.6 },
 { state: "New York", percentage: 7.56 },
 { state: "North Carolina", percentage: 2.95 },
 { state: "North Dakota", percentage: 0.28 },
 { state: "Ohio", percentage: 3.35 },
 { state: "Oklahoma", percentage: 1.14 },
 { state: "Oregon", percentage: 1.61 },
 { state: "Pennsylvania", percentage: 3.97 },
 { state: "Rhode Island", percentage: 0.43 },
 { state: "South Carolina", percentage: 1.49 },
 { state: "South Dakota", percentage: 0.34 },
 { state: "Tennessee", percentage: 1.86 },
 { state: "Texas", percentage: 7.82 },
 { state: "Utah", percentage: 0.81 },
 { state: "Vermont", percentage: 0.27 },
 { state: "Virginia", percentage: 2.5 },
 { state: "Washington", percentage: 2.45 },
 { state: "West Virginia", percentage: 0.5 },
 { state: "Wisconsin", percentage: 2.04 },
 { state: "Wyoming", percentage: 0.25 }]
```

I've adjusted the

```
data.push({
                ucName: p[0],
                value: p[1]
            });
```

to

```
stateData.push({
                state: p[0],
                percentage: p[1]
            });
```

in order to match the array of objects I am attempting to display.

Here is a link to my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0hwzyL5g/) with the actual code and objects

Comment: Hi @stepheniok, Do you want to use only data from `stateData` variable and not use html data at all?

Comment: @ppotaczek if possible yes; the html I am not including is the the list under the charts that highmaps demo shows, If possible I would like to show my data on the map without using that table. If that is the only way to do so then I will. I updated my jsfiddle link to remove the `table-div` html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adapt your data to the data structure required by Highcharts:

```
var data = stateData.map(
    el => ({
        ucName: el.state.toUpperCase(),
        value: el.percentage
    })
);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7a0s35yr/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.data